# C# Console Program Indexer only finds the FIRST item in my List<>

Tags: c#, indexer

Below is a very basic program with three classes which makes use of an Indexer to search for a person within a List<> per based on their age.

Person.cs Below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Indexer1
{
    public class Person
    {
        private string name;
        private string surname;
        private int age;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }


        public string Surname
        {
            get { return surname; }
            set { surname = value; }
        }


        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", name, surname, age);
        }

        public Person(string name, string surname, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.age = age;

        }
    }
}
```

Indexer.cs instantiates Person in List<> per Below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Indexer1
{
    public class Indexer
    {
        List<Person> per = new List<Person>();

        public Indexer()
        {
            per.Add(new Person("Joe", "Soap", 25));
            per.Add(new Person("Marry", "Jane", 82));
            per.Add(new Person("Garry", "Zuma", 37));
            per.Add(new Person("Nelson", "Mabaso", 14));
        }

        public Person this[int indexes]
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (Person item in per)
                {
                    if (item.Age == indexes)
                    {
                        return item;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                per[indexes] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs instantiates the indexer to allow for search and find, Below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Indexer1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Indexer ind = new Indexer();

            Console.WriteLine("enter in age of person you are searching for");
            int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", ind[age].Name, ind[age].Surname, ind[age].Age);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program and search for the first person added to the List<> per "Joe Soap" by entering in his age: 25 when prompted, I am able to find him successfully and display all his info.

But as soon as I search for anyone else in the List<> per, let's say "Garry Zuma" by entering in his age: 37 when prompted, the program fails and throws an exception:

***An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Indexer1.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

I have tried searching on that exception but I couldn't find anything that solved my problem.

Your guys help and assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Run your program in the debugger and go through step by step to see what your program is doing.

Comment: Aside from anything else, now would be a good time to learn about automatically implemented properties.

Comment: To expand, `private int age;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }` can simply be `public int Age {get; private set;}`. Hopefully that provides some incentive to learn about them.

Comment: Hi guys, I probably should have mentioned that I am a newby to c#. Looking at it now, it is a VERRRRRY simple problem that I had. But I appreciate the advise very much! :-)

Comment: @chris : But private variable != private set. Shouldn't it just be `public int Age {get; set;}`?

Comment: @VisualVincent, Yes, oops. I didn't look hard enough to see the public setter.

Comment: @chris : We all make mistakes sometimes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the following code from the indexer

```
else
{
   return null;
}
```

That code prevents the loop ever getting past the first item in the list

Comment: I have formatted the code in this answer, please properly format the post for the next time. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into the iteration process. Consider that In the first iteration, `if (item.Age == indexes)` is evaluates to `false` then the method will return `null` to the calling method( Rest of iterations ware skipped). So what you need to do is, Remove the `else{..}` part; SO that The method will return  `Person` object if it satisfies the condition or else will return `null` after the iteration.

```
public Person this[int indexes]
{
    get
    {
        bool isFound = false;
        foreach (Person item in per)
        {
            if (item.Age == indexes)
            {
                return item;
            }                   
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        per[indexes] = value;
    }
}
```